Get Uploading Status of any file in One Drive using GRAPH API
I am uploading one large file(approx 1GB+) from one drive site and in the backend i have one application which constantly fetches files from the one drive.
Now even though the upload is not completed yet i am able to get that file from my backend application.
I want my app to ignore the files which are not fully uploaded yet , can we do it ? , can we have uploading status like inprocess or completed or anything else
i have gone through all the properties and even expanded fields of that item from sharepoint but no luck.

Maybe it's better to track changes in One Drive by using either delta query
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
or via notifications
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#driveitem
In both cases, you will be notified once the files are fully uploaded.
